# Difference between grouping image filters and chaining image filters

Tags: ios, macos, gpuimage

Recently came across Brad Larson's [GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage) project. Confused about what to use for chaining filters.

What is the difference between using GPUImageFilterGroup and GPUImageFilterPipeline (chain of filters), vs doing addTarget: for each filter ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a matter of convenience.

When creating a GPUImageFilterGroup from a series of sub-filters, you can treat it as if it was a single filter. That means that you can remove a group from a filter chain as a unit, change targets, etc. Filter group subclasses can package commonly used filter chains into reusable units, with relevant exposed properties for tweaking.

For example, the GPUImageCannyEdgeDetectionFilter is a GPUImageFilterGroup composed of several filter steps that carry out the Canny edge detection process. You don't need to know about any of that to use this as a distinct filter, because that's abstracted away within the group.

Comment: Hi Brad, can you explain the difference between GPUImageFilterGroup and GPUImageFilterPipeline, as this was asked in the question as well?

Comment: @Andree - GPUImagePipeline is something that was contributed by another user to the project, and not something I've actively maintained or used, but basically it's a way of defining a chain of filters using a property list. It goes and creates the filters and chains them based on that list. It has had problems in the past, due to the fact that I don't use it, so I rely on others to fix those. I tend to recommend manually chaining filters or placing them in groups.